# Dashing - Twitter search term no updating

Tags: ruby, twitter, dashing

I am new to dashing and I have managed to work a lot out using the internet, however I am now at a loss as to why my widget doesn't update to the new search_term when I change it in the twitter.rb file?

I am using the default twitter.rb file with a couple of amendments. Firstly I have included my Tokens and authorisation keys from twitter.com and secondly, I have just added an extra line to receive more info when something fails in the twitter::error statement.

This is my current code (minus the keys & tokens)

```
search_term = URI::encode('#weather')

SCHEDULER.every '2m', :first_in => 0 do |job|
 begin
    tweets = twitter.search("#{search_term}")
    if tweets
      tweets = tweets.map do |tweet|
        { name: tweet.user.name, body: tweet.text, avatar: tweet.user.profile_image_url_https }
      end
      send_event('twitter_mentions', comments: tweets)
    end
  rescue Twitter::Error => e
    puts "Twitter Error: #{e}"
    puts "\e[33mFor the twitter widget to work, you need to put in your twitter API keys in the jobs/twitter.rb file.\e[0m"
  end
end
```

I have restarted Dashing; I have even rebooted the box it is on, but all to no avail. I am a total loss.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have noticed that I am also getting this error:Twitter Error: execution expired "Twitter Error: execution expired". I am researching this error.

Comment: Update:
I have now found out that it might be a timeout issue.

Some code provided is:

Twitter.configure do |config|

  # open_timeout is the maximum mount of time that the HTTP adapter will wait to
  # open a connection to the server.
  # Once the connection is established it has timeout seconds to respond.
  # the &gt things are of course > but you're against the limitation of my markup now ;-)
  config.connection_options = Twitter::Default::CONNECTION_OPTIONS.merge(:request => {
    :open_timeout => 10,
    :timeout => 20
  })
end

Comment: Does anyone know how to add this to the ruby file including the above code please? I am not a programmer, so not too sure. I did give it a go, but I keep getting errors, so where I have placed the code is obviously incorrect.